# Docker ENTRYPOINT shell script

Tags: shell, docker, docker-run

I have this in a Dockerfile

```
WORKDIR /app
COPY run.sh .
ENTRYPOINT ./run.sh
```

it says it cant find run.sh, but when I do

```
WORKDIR /app
COPY run.sh .
ENTRYPOINT bash run.sh
```

then it works. Why would this be?

Answer (score 0):

I could make it work using the first Dockerfile, but I needed to set execute permissions for run.sh. This works:

```
FROM alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY run.sh .
RUN chmod +x run.sh
ENTRYPOINT ./run.sh
```

Check if that works for you. The second version works without the permissions because it is straight passed to the `bash` interpreter, which will not check for the executable flag.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like run.sh is not executable. Have you set the executable bit for run.sh (like `chmod +x run.sh`)?